# Calculate VIP levels in googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have to solve a problem of allocating the right VIP level to users according to their monthly performance. If points are achieved, a user is moved to a specific level.
I reach this easily with the `filter` function.
Now, to keep his status from previous month, user must at least achieve a certain amount of points. If he does not, he is downgraded to previous level.

Example:

The VIP levels are the following:

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| level # | Level    | Min Points | Max Points | Keep level Points |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 1       | BRONZE   | 0          | 1875       | 0                 |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 2       | SILVER   | 1875       | 9375       | 1875              |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 3       | GOLD     | 9375       | 37500      | 9375              |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 4       | PLATINUM | 37500      | 93750      | 37500             |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 5       | DIAMOND  | 93750      | 187500     | 93750             |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 6       | ASTEROID | 187500     | 562500     | 187500            |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
```

For example, if a user generates 40000 points in the month, he is promoted to PLATINUM. It also means that next month, if he does not reach a superior level (DIAMOND OR ASTEROID), he needs to generate at least 37500 points to keep his level, or he will be downgraded to GOLD.

Taking a specific user example, I could build a model to find the right level for each month but using several rows to iterate through the months. (googlesheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ttewvIKrlCccn7xze3ZXb4i-DlKhzm1S4UhWkbxZ-mk/edit?usp=sharing))

It can be summarized by this result:

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Month | 07-2019 | 08-2019 | 09-2019 | 10-2019 | 11-2019 | 12-2019 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| UserX | 1765    | 15408   | 1383    | 1499    | 9379    | 4161    |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Level | BRONZE  | GOLD    | SILVER  | BRONZE  | GOLD    | SILVER  |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Now, having hundreds of users, I want to find the formula to calculate the right level for each month without using several rows to do so (1 row per user only)

Could anyone help to find out the solution?

Comment: can you provide example of desired output in your sheet?

Comment: i have added a sheet 'desired result' to show the desired output in the google sheets included above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste where you need it and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A4:$A9="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4:B9, 
 {0,      "BRONZE"; 
  1875,   "SILVER";
  9375,   "GOLD";
  37500,  "PLATINUM";
  93750,  "DIAMOND";
  187500, "ASTEROID"}, 2, 1))))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YmfFvqcFAjlY1QVpGsQc60WqBc9kOzk1YBkstFnon-I/edit#gid=727408538)

---

## UPDATE:

for 1 rank down use above formula in B13 and in C13 paste this formula and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IF(IF($A4:$A9="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(C4:C9, 
 {0, 1; 1875, 2; 9375, 3; 37500, 4; 93750, 5; 187500, 6}, 2, 1)))+1< IF($A4:$A9="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4:B9, 
 {0, 1; 1875, 2; 9375, 3; 37500, 4; 93750, 5; 187500, 6}, 2, 1))),   IF($A4:$A9="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4:B9, 
 {0, 1; 1875, 2; 9375, 3; 37500, 4; 93750, 5; 187500, 6}, 2, 1)))-1, IF($A4:$A9="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(C4:C9, 
 {0, 1; 1875, 2; 9375, 3; 37500, 4; 93750, 5; 187500, 6}, 2, 1)))), 
 {1, "BRONZE"; 
  2, "SILVER";
  3, "GOLD";
  4, "PLATINUM";
  5, "DIAMOND";
  6, "ASTEROID"}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YmfFvqcFAjlY1QVpGsQc60WqBc9kOzk1YBkstFnon-I/edit#gid=321853956)

Comment: I think he want the down grade only for 1 level, from gold only to silver level

Comment: Hello genius ;) very clever indeed. The only issue I see in your demo is cell C17. User is promoted to ASTEROID but on the following month he is downgraded to the minimum level (BRONZE) when he should only lower one category (down to DIAMOND)

Comment: @player0 could you help find a way to maintain the downgrade consistent after 2 downgrades?